# Actulizar elementos de un DATAGRIDVIEW en C# usando una Base de Datos y un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: c#, base-de-datos

este es mi problema, he creado una base de datos la cual tiene 2 tablas, la informacion de ambas tablas la muestra en un DATAGRIDVIEW que cree en visual studio, todo bien hasta ahi, ahora lo que quiero hacer es actualizar los registros que tengo en mi DATAGRIDVIEW, cree un procedimiento almacenado:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_ActualizarContacto; CREATE PROCEDURE
sp_ActualizarContacto(

 IN p_nombre VARCHAR (500), IN p_telefono INT (20), IN p_email VARCHAR
(500), IN p_tipocontacto VARCHAR (500))

BEGIN
> 
UPDATE contacto SET nombre = p_nombre, telefono = p_telefono, email =
p_email, tipoContacto = p_tipocontacto WHERE p_id = id_contacto;

END
```

bien, con ese procedimiento lo llamo desde visualstudio en un boton que cree que se llama actualizar, este es el codigo:

```
private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query_actualizar = "CALL sp_ActualizarContacto";

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query_actualizar, conectar);
            conectar.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("El contacto seleccionado se ha modificado exitosamente");
            mostrarContactos();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "" + ex.Number);
        }
        finally
        {
            conectar.Close();
        }

    }
```

Pero no actualiza nada en el GRIDVIEW y me arroja el sig, error :

```
INCORRECT NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS FOR PROCEDURE
CONTACTOS.SP_ACTUALIZARCONTACTO; EXPECTED 4 GOT 0 1318
```

Comment: y los parametros del SP donde los pasas?

Comment: Hola, si es lo que miraba, pero no se como agregarlos, intendo con esto: "CALL sp_ActualizarContacto('" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["nombre"].Value.ToString() + "')"; y a si con los demas parametros pero no funciona

Comment: estas usando un command... debes pasarle los parametros al command..

Comment: Disculpa la ignoracia hermano, pero como hago eso?

Answer (score 1):

Para ejecutar un Procedimiento almacenado, es necesario indicárselo al comando usando la propiedad `CommandType`, es posible que ese sea tu problema:

```
MySqlCommand cmd  = new MySqlCommand("sp_ActualizarContacto", conn);

// debe poner como tipo del comando StoredProcedure para que se ejecute correctamente
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//Añades los parámetros necesarios
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_nombre", txtNombre.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_telefono", maskedTextBox1.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_email", txtCorreo.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_tipocontacto", comboBox1.Text);
conectar.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la duda de si necesitas usar CALL para llamar al SP o no. Por lo menos en SQL server y Oracle no lo necesitas.

Mas alla de eso, debes pasarle los parametros usando:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query_actualizar, conectar);
cmd .Parameters.AddWithValue("p_nombre", variablenombre);
....
conectar.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show("El contacto seleccionado se ha modificado exitosamente");
mostrarContactos();
```

Comment: SI, bueno ya hice un procedimiento para eliminar y guardar y a si los llame con CALL y si funcionan, pero este de actualizar es el que me a traido problemas

Ese command lo agregaria aqui? 

        string query_actualizar = "CALL sp_ActualizarContacto"; (despues de esto)

Comment: te actualice la respuesta. igual deberias leer como funciona la clase mysqlcommand para entender como funciona

Comment: Lo intente a si pero me aparece el error: INCORRECT NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS FOR PROCEDURE
CONTACTOS.SP_ACTUALIZARCONTACTO; EXPECTED 4 GOT 0 1318

Comment: mandaste los 4 parametros?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_nombre", txtNombre.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_telefono", maskedTextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_email", txtCorreo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_tipocontacto", comboBox1.Text); a si los agregue

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto, actualiza y ordena de forma descendente los datos de la base de datos:

```
private void ActualizarDatos()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security=True"; //Aqui pones tus parámetros
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string consulta = "select * from MiSensualTabla ORDER BY ID DESC ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adaptador.Fill(dt);

        MiAmorosoDataGrid.DataSource = dt;

        conn.Close();

        MiAmorosoDataGrid.Update();
        MiAmorosoDataGrid.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: el problema es el insert, no la actualizacion de la grilla...